# Android Studio doesn't show after disconnecting secondary display

Tags: android, android-studio, screen

I have opened Android Studio on my second screen, then close it and disconnect the display. Next launch on Android Studio is in the secondary screen even the display is disconnected and isn't able to move on main screen.

Comment: Hi there, this seems to be a hardware problem and not a programming problem. I wonder if this question is a better fit for https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem. Used the instructions from https://superuser.com/a/98035, ie. "maximized" the Android Studio window, pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>, selected (with keyboard arrows) option "Move" and then pressed right arrow. Window snapped to my cursor and I was able to move it to desired position and maximize on correct screen.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this successfully:

1. Open Android Studio and be sure is not minimized
2. Display Settings - Scale and layout
3. Change from 100% to 125% and back it to 100%